# The kernel of the symmetrizing map.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Define the symmetrizing map:
$S: \mathbb{Q}[x_1,...x_n]\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}[f_1,...f_n], f\mapsto \frac{1}{n!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\sigma\cdot f$
where $f_i$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials and the action $\cdot$ is the permutation of variables.
We have that if there exists a $\sigma\in S_n$ such that $\sigma\cdot f = -f$, then $S(f)=0.$ Does the converse hold?

Answer (score 0):

Take the polynomial $f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=x_1^2+a_2x_2^2+a_3x_3^2$, ($a_2$,$a_3$ are determined later). You can check that if $S(f)=0$ then $a_2,a_3$ must satisfy $2+a_2+a_3=0$. Taking $a_2=\frac{3}{2}$ forces $a_3$ to be $\frac{-7}{2}$. Hence for this polynomial there is no $\sigma$ such that $\sigma (f) = -f$